# Regex to check for match and split string

Tags: .net, regex

Given a string in the following format:

```
xxx (aaa - bbb - CC-dd - ee-FFF)
```

I need to write a regex that returns a match if there are more than 3 " - " strings inside the parenthesis.

It also needs to split the string (by " - " - space, hyphen, space) and return each of those groups in a separate match. 
So given the above string, I expect the following matches:

1. aaa
2. bbb
3. CC-dd
4. ee-FFF

I have the following regex...

```
\((([\w]).*(.[-].*?){3,}([\w]))\)
```

but I'm struggling to split the string and return the matches I need.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Because it sounds like splitting on `" - "` might be easier ...

Comment: Yes I'd prefer a regex solution.

Comment: Why not simply do this in two steps? 1. capture everything between parentheses , 2. Split on ` - ` ?

Comment: It will be a very ugly regex, something like `\((?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)(?: - (?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)){2,}\)` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%3f%3co%3e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!+-+%29%5b%5e%28%29%5d%29%2b%29%28%3f%3a+-+%28%3f%3co%3e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!+-+%29%5b%5e%28%29%5d%29%2b%29%29%7b2%2c%7d%5c%29&i=xxx+%28aaa+-+bbb+CC-+dd+-+ee-FFF%29)). But it will do both validation and extraction (get all the captures of the "o" group).

Comment: @maccettura Correct, that's why I expect CC-dd not to be split and be part of one group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex based on a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
\((?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)(?: - (?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)){3,}\)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%3f%3co%3e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!+-+%29%5b%5e%28%29%5d%29%2b%29%28%3f%3a+-+%28%3f%3co%3e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!+-+%29%5b%5e%28%29%5d%29%2b%29%29%7b3%2c%7d%5c%29&i=xxx+%28aaa+-+bbb+CC+-+dd+-+ee-FFF%29%0d%0axxx+%28aaa+-+bbb+CC-+dd-+ee-FFF%29)

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)` - Group "o": any char other than `(` and `)`, 1 or more occurrences, not starting the `space-space` sequence
- `(?: - (?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)){3,}` - three or more occurrences of

  - `-`  - space `-` space
  - `(?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)` - Group "o": any char other than `(` and `)`, 1 or more occurrences, not starting the `space-space` sequence
- `\)` - a `)` char

Get all the Group "o" captures to extract the values.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/PjhpCj):

```
var s = "xxx (aaa - bbb CC - dd - ee-FFF) (aaa2 - bbb2 CC2- dd2- ee2-FFF2)";
var pattern = @"\((?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)(?: - (?<o>(?:(?! - )[^()])+)){3,}\)";
var ms = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);
foreach (Match m in ms) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Matched: {m.Value}");
    var res = m.Groups["o"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", res));
}
```

Output:

```
Matched: (aaa - bbb CC - dd - ee-FFF)
aaa; bbb CC; dd; ee-FFF
```

Comment: Ok, I tested on the sample text OP had at the beginning, and I understood there must be 3 items, not `space-space` substrings. Well, only the quantifier should be adjusted then, the approach is still valid.

Comment: Your linked answer mentions that the performance for this technique might be sub-par. I believe it could be fair to reiterate this warning here because I've witnessed first-hand that regexps in .NET can take a ridiculous amount of time to execute in certain cases, especially if the input is user-provided.

Comment: @SirDarius Well, we are talking about .NET regex here, and it is much more powerful than others. I just tested with `\((?<o>(?: (?!- )|[^() ])+)(?: - (?<o>(?: (?!- )|[^() ])+)){3,}\)` and it shows just a 0.7% increase in performance. `\((?<o>[^() ]*(?: (?!- )[^() ]*)*)(?: - (?<o>[^() ]*(?: (?!- )[^() ]*)*)){3,}\)` is 30% faster, but it may match empty items in Group "o".

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be rephrased like this:

You need to split the text between parentheses using " - " as a delimiter, and determine if there are 4 or more text fragments.

How I would do this:

1. Use a regexp to get the text, something like: `\(([^\)]+)\)`
2. split the matched text using String.Split(" - ")
3. check that the number of elements in the returned array is > 3

This looks more maintainable than a huge regular expression, and should be equivalent in terms of performance, if not faster.